# "Los almacenes de claves en formato PKCS12 no admiten contraseñas de clave y almacenamiento distintas" al crear claves de firma en Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy intentando firmar una aplicación para publicarla siguiendo los pasos de [esta página](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key).
Al crear el Almacén de Claves con su password y después la Clave con su propio password tal como indican en esa página, una vez rellenos todos los campos y pulsado el OK, recibo el siguiente mensaje de de error:

> Advertencia: los almacenes de claves en formato PKCS12 no admiten contraseñas de clave y almacenamiento distintas. Se ignorará el valor especificado por el usuario, -keypass.

Ocurre lo mismo ya elija firmar como Signed Bundle o como APK. También he probado a ponerles la misma password a ambos (Almacén y Clave) y el problema, al menos éste, desaparece. La cuestión es: ¿hago bien en ponerles la misma password cuando la página de Desarrolladores de Google me dice que éstas deben ser distintas?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno parece que he encontrado la respuesta. En este [enlace](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?hl=sv) hay un apartado que dice:

> Error when using different passwords for key and keystore
>
> Starting with version 4.2, Android Studio now runs on JDK 11. This
> update causes an underlying behavior change related to signing keys.
>
> When you navigate to Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK and attempt
> to configure app signing for an app bundle or an APK, entering
> different passwords for the key and keystore may result in the
> following error:
>
> Key was created with errors: Warning: Different store and Key
> passwords not supported for PKCS12 Key stores
>
> To work around this issue, enter the same password for both the key
> and keystore.

La respuesta está clara: las mismas password y ya está... Lo que no comprendo es por qué los que han creado el IDE no lo cambian para evitar las pérdidas de tiempo a las que nos obligan. Espero que la trabajera le sirva a alguien más... Un saludo.